# Force ggplot to show 2 curve function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have two function `y1` and `y2`.

If I plot them individually no problem (cf. two first figures).

However, if I combine them, the shape looks linear (cf. figure 3) .

How can I solve that?

```
x  <- seq(0, 50, 1) ;x
y1 <- exp(8.9191)+exp^(0.03307*x)
y2 <- exp(9.9191)+exp^(0.06307*x)
df <- data.frame(x,y1,y2)

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +                  
  geom_line(aes(y=y2), colour="red")  #Looks nice (curvy)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +                  
  geom_line(aes(y=y1), colour="blue") #Looks nice (curvy)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +                    
  geom_line(aes(y=y1), colour="blue") +  
  geom_line(aes(y=y2), colour="red")  #Looks not nice linear
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... because they are on hugely different scales?  This is going to be almost impossible to reconcile: since there are large additive constants, even adding a logarithmic vertical scale won't help much.

Comment: What are you trying to compare? Perhaps there is a better way of representing the data.

Comment: The red curve represents women and the blue men. So I try to compare the difference between man and woman. The x axis represents nothing in my example. However, you can imagine that the x axis is working experience, and the y axis can represent the wages, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `facet_grid()` and the scales option.
You will have two facets, each with a different y scale.

```
require(reshape2)
mdf <- melt(data.frame(y1, y2))
mdf$x <- x

ggplot(mdf, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value)) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I guess it's indeed the best solution.